# SQL query IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server

I want to check data exists in another table..

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IndicatorData]
(
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [float] NOT NULL,
    [indicatorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [uploaded] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [createdBy] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [createdOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [lastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [lastModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataFields] 
(
    [dataId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [fieldId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

`IndicatorData.id` has a relationship with `DataFields.dataid` (`IndicatorData.id` can have multiple combination of datafield)

Table IndicatorData sample data:

[image]

Table DataFields sample data:

[image]

Query I tried:

**Note**: I won't pass dataid, I will pass only field id & indicatorid

**Scenario #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM IndicatorData a 
INNER JOIN  DataFields b ON a.id = b.dataid  
WHERE a.indicatorid = 72 
  AND b.fieldid IN (59, 207)
```

[image]

When I pass the field id, i need to get the combination of the values with dataid.

Output should return like this:

[image]

Kindly suggest how I can achive this

Comment: Your query looks fine to me - what isn't working?

Comment: you can see Scaneiro #1 and compare the ouput.. you can find the difference

Comment: Not quite clear what you want, do you mean you only want output of the id with same value and with multiple records? i.e. in scenario 1 output, record with id=69137 is NOT what you want in the outuput?

Comment: sorry..i have edited the the post...kindly check it and let me know your suggestion

Comment: Given the data you show, I can't see how you determine that id=69137 should be excluded - are you looking only for cases when the given indicator has *both* fieldID 59 and 207?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
;with c as (
SELECT a.id, cnt = count(*) from IndicatorData a 
INNER JOIN  DataFields b ON a.id=b.dataid  
where a.indicatorid = 72 and b.fieldid in(59,207)
group by a.id 
having count(*) > 1
) 
select a.*, b.* from IndicatorData a INNER JOIN  DataFields b 
ON a.id=b.dataid
inner join c
on a.id = c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the requirement, you could as the below:

```
SELECT * from 
    IndicatorData a INNER JOIN  
    DataFields b ON a.id=b.dataid  
WHERE 
    a.indicatorid = 72 AND 
    a.id IN 
        (
            SELECT df.id FROM DataFields df 
            WHERE df.fieldid IN (59,207) 
            GROUP BY df.dataId  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

        )
```